# pandas to_csv: how to format floats in a column with mixed types

Tags: csv, pandas

I have a df which contains a column with both float and text values.

df.some_column

```
0    48.5182
1    58.2259
2    some string
3    48.5182
4    17.4928
```

I want to write all the values to CSV with floats rounded to 0 decimals. So the values in this column would be:

```
48
58
some string
48
17
```

When I write this to CSV with

`df.to_csv(output_path,encoding='utf-8', index=False, float_format='%.0f')`

the `float_format` is ignored and I get decimal values.  If I remove the rows with strings first, the `float_format`is used as expected.  I looked around for a way to convert the values to int, but didn't find a way to do that on the column.

It looks like I could possibly iterate through all the values and round them, but I suspect there is some more elegant way.

Comment: I have a very similar question with date_format but the answer is extremely specific to what the questioner wants to do - is there any way to actually specify float_format and date_format in mixed Series or DataFrame columns rather than perform tricks after string conversion?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could cast the `dtype` to `str` and then split on the decimal point and take the whole number part:

```
In [70]:    
df['some_col'] = df['some_col'].astype(str)
df['some_col'] = df['some_col'].loc[df['some_col'].str.contains('.')].str.split('.').str[0]
df

Out[70]:
          some_col
index             
0               48
1               58
2      some string
3               48
4               17
```

Then when you call `to_csv` you don't need the `float_format` param